# How to import the `module` class?

Tags: python

I want to work on the `module` class in Python, but I don't know how to find it. I know I can get it as follows:

```py
>>> import os
>>> type(os)  # This is what I want
<class 'module'>
```

but I was wondering if there is any cleaner way to import it. The following does not work:

```py
>>> type(os).__module__
'builtins'
>>> from builtins import module  # OK so let's import it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'module' from 'builtins' (unknown location)
```

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? *Why* do you think you want to access the `module` class?

Comment: I'm mostly curious of the correct way to import it. I'm just exploring, looking at the methods, seeing if there is any point subclassing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType):

```
>>> import types
>>> types.ModuleType
<class 'module'>
>>>
```

[`types`] is a module which helps you to deal with types, as in the docs:

> This module defines utility functions to assist in dynamic creation of new types.

There it tells you:

> Finally, it provides some additional type-related utility classes and functions that are not fundamental enough to be builtins.

That is why it is not in the builtins.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it weird that `type(os).__module__` is `'builtins'` then?

Comment: @RoméoDesprés Every type says that tho